# I'm trying to go make an app but keep getting the following error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

This is my code, I saw another question with the same but it was for an earlier version of react and had classes and constructors
initially `this.setState` was `this.state` but I changed it due to warnings from VS code

```
    function App() {
    this.setState({
      input:'',
  })
  this.onInputChange= (event)=> {
    console.log(event)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Particles className="particles" params={particlesOptions} />
      <Navigation />
      <Logo />
      <Rank />
      <ImageLinkForm onInputChange={this.onInputChange} />
      {/* <FaceRecognition/> */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Function components don't have a this.setState, use hooks. Or just stick with the class components, they still work fine.

Comment: Could you explain? @jonrsharpe

Comment: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do.You are trying to update state in a functionnal component as it was a class based component.If you work with functions, the way to provide state is by import the `useState` `hook`.From what i've understood in what you're trying to do here is a code that is compatible with using state in `functionnal components`

```
import React,{useState} from "react";

 function App() {
    const [input,setInput]=useState("");

  const onInputChange= (event)=> {
    setInput(event.target.value)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Particles className="particles" params={particlesOptions} />
      <Navigation />
      <Logo />
      <Rank />
      <ImageLinkForm onInputChange={onInputChange} />
      {/* <FaceRecognition/> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

For more information read the documentation has a very good explanation : [Using the State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)